# Kolmogorov dilations of positive definite kernels and Donsker's Delta

Tags: probability

I'm having problems understanding a part of the proof of Kolmogorov’s dilation theorem (Theorem 3.2 given in [this](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Emaassen/lectures/qp.pdf)).

We define a map $V_K:S\to H$ given by $V_K(x):=\delta_x+N$. Then, we compute the inner-product of two such functions:
\begin{align}
\langle V_K(x),V_K(y) \rangle &= \langle \delta_x+N,\delta_y+N \rangle_{L/N}\tag{1.1} \\&= \langle \delta_x, \delta_y \rangle_L\tag{1.2} \\&= \sum_{x'\in S} \sum_{y'\in S} \delta_x(x') K(x',y') \delta_y(y')\tag{1.3}\\&=K(x,y)\,,\tag{1.4}
\end{align}
where $x,y\in S$.

From such an equation, I deduce $\delta_x\in L$, so that $\delta_x:S\to \mathbb{C}$ has finite support. I haven't taken a course on Probability Theory, but from what I have searched, it seems that $\delta_x(x')$ is a Donsker's Delta (see definition 3.1 in [this](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10247/1/pm06-98.pdf)).

Donsker's Delta satisfies the condition (which seems suitable in this context) that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\int g(y)\delta_Y(y)dy=g(Y),
\end{equation}
for almost every $y\in S$, and all measurable functions $g$. Also, this property seems pretty similar to the one used in $(1.4)$: by interchanging the integral by a sum in $(2)$.

My question is if my reasoning about the function $\delta_x$ is correct and why it was required for the proof? (is there another option?)